# Change the class of the Assets buttons in a Safecracker form

Tags: safecracker, assets, css, bootstrap

I have Assets 2.0.3 as a field in a Safecracker form. The buttons created by Assets have the class "assets-btn", leaving me with pink buttons.

Rather than overriding CSS for these buttons I would rather use a different class to use the styling of Twitter Bootstrap.

Is this possible?

(The styling in Assets 1 was far more generic and preferable for including in  Safecracker form.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon,

currently that is not possible, but you can wrap the safecracker form in an element with an id specified and then apply some CSS overrides based on that.

We have discussed better Safecracker support, but we'll have to see how it pans out - we have a couple of ideas that should make people excited - we just have to finalize them and then implement them.